# How to add DNS suffix in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: dns

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04. And I am a beginner on Linux. So, how can I add the DNS suffix in this OS. Please help..

Comment: Right now I got no Ubuntu install to test this with, but the normal way to do this is by adding a new line with `search mydomain.tld` in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by DNS suffix?

Answer (score 10):

In the past you did this by modifying `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Now `/etc/resolv.conf` is managed by `resolvconf`.  So now you do:

- Create a file named `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`
- Add the line `search mydomain.tld` to that file
- Run `sudo resolvconf -u`

Answer (score 4):

For static ipaddresses this can be defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`
eg:

```
dns-search na.my-domain.net
```

see
[What does the dns-search option mean in /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265811/what-does-mean-dns-seach-option-in-etc-network-interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

In Debian and Ubuntu the system hostname is a short name --- this name does not have a domain name suffix. Domain name suffixes for a machine are determined by DNS which is outside the machine itself.

Certain applications running on the local machine need to be given one or more fully qualified domain names for the local machine. Those applications should be configured accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by adding...

```
append domain-name "na.my-domain.net";
```

to..

```
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

and then...

```
sudo restart network-manager
```