# Lookup DNS entry by hostname without FQDN

Tags: 14.04, server, dns

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server that has the AD role installed on it. All machines, Linux and Windows use the AD DNS server for name resolution. When making DNS queries on Linux using NSLookup I have to type the FQDN (mynode.domain.com). But in Windows, I only need the hostname (mynode). So, my question is, is there a way to just use hostnames on Ubuntu?

Here is the output I get when trying just the hostname:

```
Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.0.2, trying next server
...
server can't find mynode: NXDOMAIN
```

Any help with this, as always, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329231/how-to-add-dns-suffix-in-ubuntu-12-04), you must add the the DNS domain name (Zone) to `/etc/network/interfaces` in the following way:

```
dns-search domain.com
```

Comment: You don't have to be sorry; in this case, you had to know what to look for. Depending on the file/utility used, it's called different things. `/etc/resolv.conf`, for example, calls it just `search`.