# DNS issues with Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: networking, dns

The issue that I am facing is the following:

I have configured a vm Ubuntu and the machine isn't able to resolve DNS records with my internal DNS server. "The DNS server is a windows_server_2008_R2 AD/DNS combo"

The topology:
[image: Topology]

Ubuntu configuration:

```
root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
          address 192.168.1.12
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          dns-nameservers 172.16.1.11 144.254.71.184
          gateway 192.168.1.1



root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0



root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf

Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.16.1.11
nameserver 144.254.71.184
```

The vm wimdows_7 machine that is in the same network as the Ubuntu "using the same DNS server" is able to get the results.

ASA configuration "traffic going from high > low security, required inspection is in place"

Took captures on the ASA to see what is happening, the weird thing that I saw was the fact that in Ubuntu "not working situation" the query is going to 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa 
[image: ubuntu_cap]
In windows "working situation" the query is going to 1.1.16.172.in-addr.arpa 
 [image: windows_cap]

keep in mind that the windows server IP is 172.16.1.11 and the DNS records are all there [image: dns_config_windows]

ping\nslookup from windows_7

```
C:\Users\administrator>ping 172.16.1.11
Pinging 172.16.1.11 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.16.1.11: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 172.16.1.11:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
Control-C
^C

C:\Users\administrator>nslookup rboshmaf-ubuntu 172.16.1.11

Server:  win-o33saf37ksq.raedlab.local

Address:  172.16.1.11

Name:    rboshmaf-ubuntu.raedlab.local

Address:  192.168.1.12
```

ping\nslookup fom Ubuntu

```
root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# ping 172.16.1.11
PING 172.16.1.11 (172.16.1.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.1.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.25 ms
^C
--- 172.16.1.11 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.258/1.258/1.258/0.000 ms

root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# nslookup rboshmaf-ubuntu 172.16.1.11
Server:         172.16.1.11
Address:        172.16.1.11#53

** server can't find rboshmaf-ubuntu: SERVFAIL
```

What I don't like in the capture is the fact that Ubuntu query is going to 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa which isn't the DNS server "in fact 192.168.1.1 is the GW for Ubuntu "inside interface of the ASA"

Any ideas or suggestion about the situation.

Thanks!

edit #1

Just to remove the ASA from the picture, I reconfigured the Topology as following:

[image: new_topology]

New Ubuntu configuration:

```
   root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
     # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
     auto lo
     iface lo inet loopback
     auto eth0
     iface eth0 inet static
           address 172.16.1.12
           netmask 255.255.255.0
           dns-nameservers 172.16.1.11 144.254.71.184
           gateway 172.16.1.1

   root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# ifconfig
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:99:3c:b3  
             inet addr:172.16.1.12  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:20756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:6959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:29614255 (29.6 MB)  TX bytes:480744 (480.7 KB)

   root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
   # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by 
   resolvconf(8)
   #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
   nameserver 172.16.1.11
   nameserver 144.254.71.184

   root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# route
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
   Iface
   default         172.16.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 
   eth0
   link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 
   eth0
   172.16.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 
   eth0
```

ping/nslookup from Ubuntu

```
root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# ping 172.16.1.11
PING 172.16.1.11 (172.16.1.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.1.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.811 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.981 ms
^C
--- 172.16.1.11 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.811/1.007/1.231/0.176 ms
root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# nslookup rboshmaf-ubuntu 172.16.1.11
Server:     172.16.1.11
Address:    172.16.1.11#53

** server can't find rboshmaf-ubuntu: SERVFAIL
```

capture for the ASA confirming no traffic reached the ASA

```
rboshmaf-asa# capture cap1 interface dmz match ip h 172.16.1.12 h 172.16.1.11
rboshmaf-asa# show capture
capture cap1 type raw-data interface dmz [Capturing - 0 bytes]
  match ip host 172.16.1.12 host 172.16.1.11
```

And I took tcpdump on ubuntu

```
root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# tcpdump -n -i eth0 | grep 172.16.1.11.53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:17:07.417553 IP 172.16.1.12.54685 > 172.16.1.11.53: 43282+ A? rboshmaf-ubuntu. (33)
10:17:07.418939 IP 172.16.1.11.53 > 172.16.1.12.54685: 43282 ServFail 0/0/0 (33)
10:17:27.270067 IP 172.16.1.12.56675 > 172.16.1.11.53: 50648+ A? ntp.ubuntu.com. (32)
10:17:27.270803 IP 172.16.1.11.53 > 172.16.1.12.56675: 50648 3/0/0 A 91.189.89.198, A 91.189.89.199, A 91.189.91.157 (80)
```

And the local capture from the windows_server[image: new_capture]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the machine didn't know what FQDN to search in, I edited /etc/network/interfaces to include "dns-search raedlab.local"

```
rboshmaf@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.12
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      dns-nameservers 172.16.1.11 144.254.71.184
      gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-search raedlab.local < this was missing in my configuration

rboshmaf@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~$ nslookup rboshmaf-ubuntu 172.16.1.11
Server:     172.16.1.11
Address:    172.16.1.11#53

Name:   rboshmaf-ubuntu.raedlab.local
Address: 192.168.1.12
```

Also you can check this post on askubuntu for information about what dns-search does [What does the dns-search option mean in /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265811/what-does-the-dns-search-option-mean-in-etc-network-interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are:

1. DNS server isn't accepting requests on port 53. Try using `telnet` on port `53` to test this.
2. If the flows are ok, please check your `/etc/hosts` from Ubuntu, might have a local record which might create a conflict.
3. If the above doesn't give you an answer, maybe there is something wrong with the configuration of DNS server. Make sure you have the A record provisioned as well as a NS record for authority.

Comment: The Ubuntu machine is back behind the inside interface of the ASA and it has it's 192.168.1.12 IP

Comment: 1. Telnet is working "If the server is returning results most likely the connections are happening don't you think"                                                                                       
                                                                                        
 root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# telnet 172.16.1.11 53
Trying 172.16.1.11...
Connected to 172.16.1.11.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: 2. Here is the local hosts                                                  root@rboshmaf-ubuntu:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: 3. I am pretty sure DNS is configured correctly, you can check it from the screenshot above. Also how can you explain the fact that DNS is working for windows and not Ubuntu to be an issue from the DNS server and not the Ubuntu client "if you check the Ubuntu query that is listed above you will see that it is weird"

Comment: Can you try nslookup with the FQDN rather than the shortname? From the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Tried it and it is working                                                              nslookup rboshmaf-ubuntu.raedlab.local 172.16.1.11
Server:  172.16.1.11
Address: 172.16.1.11#53

Name: rboshmaf-ubuntu.raedlab.local
Address: 192.168.1.12

Comment: Thanks! your comment pointed me to the correct direction. The issue was I didn't tell my machine what FQDN to use. I edited /etc/metwork/interfaces to include "dns-search raedlab.local" and vuala it is able to resolve short-host names